Flutter AdMob Native Ad: Action triggered on tap anywhere within ad, but want action only on button press
I'm integrating AdMob Native ads into my Flutter app, and I'm facing an issue where tapping anywhere within the ad triggers the associated action. However, I only want the action to be invoked when the user presses the action button within the ad.
Here's a snippet of my Android code related to displaying the native ad: I am android novice. I had compiled this code looking at the docs and using chatgpt.
feed_ad_1.xml
<com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:background="#000000"
      android:gravity="bottom"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dip"
        android:layout_marginEnd="34dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.04"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip">

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/ad_attribution_1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="@string/ad_attribution_label2"
          android:textAlignment="center"
          android:textColor="@color/gnt_gray"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.MediaView
        android:id="@+id/ad_media"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ad_headline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.38"
        android:fontFamily="@font/teko_regular"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.9"
        android:paddingStart="34dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:paddingEnd="70dip"
        android:paddingBottom="30dip"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dip"
        android:layout_marginEnd="34dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.04"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip">

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/ad_attribution_2"
          android:layout_width="40dip"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:background="@color/gnt_gray"
          android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="@string/ad_attribution_label1"
          android:textAlignment="center"
          android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
          android:textSize="16sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/ad_advertiser"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:layout_marginStart="14dip"
          android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
          android:gravity="start|center"
          android:textAlignment="textStart"
          android:textColor="@color/gnt_gray"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ad_call_to_action"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dip"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dip"
        android:background="@drawable/button_rounded"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
        android:minHeight="52dip"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
  </LinearLayout>
</com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView>

FeedItemAdFactory.java
package com.myapp.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.MediaView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView;
import io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.NativeAdFactory;
import java.util.Map;

class FeedItemAdFactory implements NativeAdFactory {
    private final Context context;

    FeedItemAdFactory(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public NativeAdView createNativeAd(
            NativeAd nativeAd, Map<String, Object> customOptions) {
        final NativeAdView adView =
                (NativeAdView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.feed_ad_1, null);

        adView.setMediaView((MediaView) adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_media));

        adView.setHeadlineView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_headline));
        adView.setCallToActionView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_call_to_action));
        adView.setAdvertiserView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_advertiser));

        String headlineText = nativeAd.getHeadline();
        if (nativeAd.getBody() != null) {
            headlineText += "\n" + nativeAd.getBody();
        }
        ((TextView) adView.getHeadlineView()).setText(headlineText);

        adView.getMediaView().setMediaContent(nativeAd.getMediaContent());

        if (nativeAd.getCallToAction() == null) {
            adView.getCallToActionView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            adView.getCallToActionView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((Button) adView.getCallToActionView()).setText(nativeAd.getCallToAction());
        }
        adView.getIconView()).setImageDrawable(nativeAd.getIcon().getDrawable());
        if (nativeAd.getAdvertiser() == null) {
            adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) adView.getAdvertiserView()).setText(nativeAd.getAdvertiser());
        }

        adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd);

        return adView;
    }
}

Can someone please guide me on how to ensure that the action associated with the ad is only triggered when the user presses the action button within the ad, rather than anywhere within the ad?
Thank you in advance for any assistance!
I tried adding this piece of code that chatgpt recommended but it changes nothing.

        // Wrap CTA button with GestureDetector for click handling
        Button ctaButton = (Button) adView.getCallToActionView();
        GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override // Remove this annotation
            public boolean onTap(View v) {
            // Replace with the correct method for getting the click URL from your AdMob library
            launch(nativeAd.getClickToAction() /* or appropriate method name */);
            return true;
            }
        });
        ctaButton.setOnTouchListener(gestureDetector);
        }

        // Disable clickability for the NativeAdView
        adView.setClickable(false);
        adView.setEnabled(false);

        // Disable clickability for other views
        adView.getHeadlineView().setClickable(false);
        adView.getMediaView().setClickable(false);
        adView.getAdvertiserView().setClickable(false);

        // Enable clickability for the call-to-action button
        adView.getCallToActionView().setClickable(true);
        adView.getCallToActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nativeAd.performClick(new Bundle());
            }
        });


I do not recommend mixing flutter with native code in the way you are doing. most probably the problem you are facing is connected to the way you have used the native code with flutter plugin.
I recommend using Native Ads Dart templates or platform specific dart native ads for more control over the view.
